# How to quickly fill holes

Tags: modeling, mesh

I made some belts.There are many such holes on my model.But I don't need these holes now. I used the method of deleting faces and merging points to fill them one by one. Is there a faster method or plugin?Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's any quick trick, maybe select the circle, merge at center, then do the same on the opposite side, remove the inner edge that will remain between the vertices, at the end select all and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Vertices* to remove of the useless edges.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed process and answers! I am currently using this method as well, but there are many holes that require a lot of time to fill one by one, so I am asking if there are any techniques for batch filling. Thank you!